# Why is the donor level in a semiconductor called a "level"?

Tags: material-science

To expand on my question - Why is the donor level in a an n-type extrinsic semi-conductor called a level instead of a band?

Shouldn't it be referred to as a band instead, as the "donated electrons" are being introduced to the semiconductor from multiple dopant atoms, not a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "width" of *dopant level* is very small, especially relative to band "width". Due to relatively low concentration of dopant atoms, thus, big distance between them, there is nearly no interaction between dopant atoms' electrons and no electron levels splitting, thus electrons of all atoms have nearly same energy and band is not formed. This can be imagined as dot line on energy diagram.

At high dopant concentration, impurity atoms became close to each other, their electron interaction becomes significant, electron levels split and form a band. Such semiconductors are called *degenerated*. Such high-doped regions usually form passive parts of devices, like ohmic contacts or emitters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_semiconductor

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Helped me clear things up and understand better!